# iOS: Table alignment and fit in UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to display a link which contains a table on a UIWebView. The table content is not fitting correctly. Below is a screen shot taken from the simulator.

[image: Table not fitting in UIWebView]

This is how I have configured the UIWebView.

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
webView.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;
webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
webView.frame=self.view.bounds;
NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.24x.com/tam/list.html";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I need to keep pinch zoom and vertical scroll enabled.

How can I get the table content to fit in properly?

/******************************************Edit***************************************/

This seems to be a problem with how I'm sending the POST request. 
On the web, there is a default.html page which takes the postcode and email of the user and calls the following function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "handler.aspx?action=postcode&page=default&value=" + PCode + "&email=" + Email + "&browser=" + strBrowser ,
    success: function (msg) {
        window.location.assign("list.html");
}
```

In the app, I'm using text fields to get the postcode and email, and then I send a POST request to handler.aspx like above. Then I load the list.html in a UIWebView.
Now, when I open the same default page in safari, the table fits correctly. This leads me to believe that the problem is in the way I'm sending the POST request or the way I'm redirecting to link.html.

Comment: It seems a problem on your list.html css. Could you post your html and css code?

Comment: what is frame of the webview

Comment: run Safari when the simulator is running, turn on Develop menu in preferences -> advanced -> bottom checkbox, if you have not already, and use the develop menu to look at the HTML & CSS to try to debug it.

Comment: Do you mean the frame size Ramesh. It's a frame rectangle 114*334.